# Spring JPA PostgreSQL + MongoDB

Tags: spring, mongodb, postgresql

Starting from the Spring example **Accessing MongoDB Data with REST** (https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-mongodb-data-rest/) I'd like to integrate a PostgreSQL data source and link it to the MongoDB repository.
By switching from `MongoRepository` to `JpaRepository` and accordingly changing the application.properties file I've been able to pass from MongoDB to PostgreSQL and viceversa, but basically having only one active data source at time.
**application.properties when using MongoDB**

```
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost/
spring.data.mongodb.database=myMongoDB_DB
spring.data.mongodb.repositories.enabled=true
```

**application.properties when using PostgreSQL**

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myPostgreSQL_DB
spring.datasource.username=me
spring.datasource.password=mySuperSecretPassword

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Is there a way to configure Spring (with an **Annotation-only** way) to link two data sources to the same Repository  so that when I access my REST web service via HTTP both MongoDB and PostgreSQL are changed in exactly the same way?
I googled around and found something about Spring cross-store support (http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.5.5.RELEASE/reference/html/mongo.cross.store.html) but it uses xml for the application configuration and AspectJ, is there a simpler way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

In this chapter you can find an answer - [(Spring-boot manual - Use Spring Data JPA and Mongo repositories)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-use-spring-data-jpa--and-mongo-repositories)