# How to use cassandra with postgres using spring-boot-starter-data

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, cassandra

I'm trying to set up a new test spring boot application using spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra and spring-boot-starter-data-jpa (PosgreSQL). Everything works fine with a single or multiple repositories of same kind (tried with two postgtesql databases), but i did not find a way to configure a multiple heterogeneous repositories. 
Does any one has an idea, how my application should be configured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use `@EnableCassandraRepositories` and `@EnableJpaRepositories` with explicit basePackages attribute, where respective repositories are located:

```
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = { "org.spring.cassandra.example.repo" })
```

and

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "org.spring.jpa.example.repo" })
```

Comment: thanks, i found also a solution for similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942300/spring-jpa-postgresql-mongodb)

Comment: how you provided db urls and driverclass name in application.yaml?

Comment: @M-sAnNan, those are your packages where are your repositories located. I guess I copied those from Spring Docs. They changed example packages since. See here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/reference/html/#cassandra.cassandra-java-config

Comment: i think we dont need to provide driverCalssName in application.yaml for Cassandra and that @EnableCassandraRepositories does the trick here. 
I was confused about how would you provide more than one driverClassName in yaml.